# How do we come up with the SVM Kernel giving $n+d\choose d$ feature space?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, polynomial

I was going through the CS229 notes on SVM and Kernel tricks and I came across the following line.

> More generally the kernel $K(x,z)=(xTz+c)^d$ corresponds to a feature
> mapping to an $n+d\choose d$ feature space, corresponding to all monomials
> that are up to order d. Despite working in this $O(n^d)$ dimensional
> space, computing $K(x,z)$ is of order $O(n)$.

Firstly, How exactly does it translate into $n+d\choose d$ feature space?
Consider I have $n = 3$ and $d = 2$, i.e, $x = [x1, x2, x3], z = [z1, z2, z3]$

so, a feature map for $K(x,z) = (xTz + c)^2$ would look something like this:
$$\phi(x) = [x_1^2, x_1x_2, x_1x_3, x_2x_1, x_2^2, x_2x_3, x_3x_1, x_3x_2, x_3^2, \sqrt{2c}x_1, \sqrt{2c}x_2, \sqrt{2c}x_3, c]$$

which makes a total of 13 features. But $3+2\choose 2$ gives me 10. It does not make sense to me.

Secondly,

> Despite working in this $O(n^d)$ dimensional space

Why does it say $n^d$ dimensional space whereas we had feature mapped to 13 dimensions?
Are we then only considering the monomials $x_{i1}x_{i2}...x_{ip}$ which make up order d = 2? (i.e, $x_1^2$ or $x_1x_2$ etc).

If that is the case, then what is this all about?

> the kernel $K(x,z)=(xTz+c)^d$ corresponds to a feature mapping to an $n+d\choose d$ feature space

This seems confusing to me. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: [Here](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes3.pdf) is the link to the pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at your $\phi$

> $$\phi(x) = [x_1^2, x_1x_2, x_1x_3, x_2x_1, x_2^2, x_2x_3, x_3x_1, x_3x_2, x_3^2, \sqrt{2c}x_1, \sqrt{2c}x_2, \sqrt{2c}x_3, c]$$

You are counting some dimensions twice: $x_1x_2=x_2x_1$, $x_1x_3=x_3x_1$, $x_2x_3=x_3x_2$.
Taking the duplicates out results in $d=10$:

$$\phi(x) = [x_1^2, x_1x_2, x_1x_3, x_2x_3, x_2^2, x_3^2, \sqrt{2c}x_1, \sqrt{2c}x_2, \sqrt{2c}x_3, c]$$

Comment: So it says "working in this $O(n^d)$ dimensional space because we added this c term that introduced an additional dimension so it is a bit more than $n^d$ ?

Comment: @shiladityabasu $\mathcal O (n^d)$ is the order of time complexity. The exact dimensionality is ${{n+d}\choose{d}}$